# Derivative of integral, evaluated at $t=0$

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

I was solving a problem and ran into this rather ugly derivative of integral, evaluated at $t=0$:

$$\frac{d^2}{dt^2}\left(\left.\int_0^1e^{tf(x)}dx\right)\right|_{t=0}$$

Is there a way to evaluate this value?

**Description of $f$**: Fix $n$. If $x\in(0,1]$ can be written in binary in non-terminating fashion as $0.a_1a_2a_3\ldots a_n\ldots$, then $f(x)$ is the number of $1$'s among $\{a_1,\ldots,a_n\}$ minus the number of $0$'s among the same set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just looking at the integral, it is acceptable for you to take the integral of the second derivative at t=0 then integrate with respect to x (derivative of integral equaling integral of derivative), although some stickler might ask you to explain why this property is acceptable, or under which conditions it is acceptable. It should look something like

$$
\begin{align*}
\frac{d^2}{dt^2}\left( \int_0^1 e^{tf(x)} dx \right)\bigg\vert_{t=0} &= \int_0^1 \left(\frac{d^2}{dt^2} e^{tf(x)} \bigg\vert_{t=0}\right)dx\\
&= \int_0^1 f(x)^2 dx.
\end{align*}
$$

Just my first inclination, I encourage a correction there if warranted.

Comment: Note: Look up "Leibniz integral rule" for differentiation under an integral if you meet that stickler.

Comment: Thanks, J.W. Perry! This matches the answer I need. Yeah, generally I feel it should be acceptable, but I'll read about the Leibniz integral rule.

Answer (score 0):

For fixed $n$, the function $f(x)$ takes on only finitely many values on the interval $(0, 1]$: the number of ones and the number of zeroes are both bounded by $n$, so $f(x)$ is an integer between $-n$ and $n$.

Write
$$E_k = \bigg\{ x \in (0, 1] \; \bigg| \; f(x) = k\bigg\}$$

for $-n \leq k \leq n$, and write the integral as

$$\int_0^1 e^{t f(x)} \, dx = \sum_{k=-n}^n \int_{E_k} e^{tk} \, dx= \sum_{k=-n}^n e^{tk} \int_{E_k} \, dx$$

So the problem just reduces to finding the lengths of the sets $E_k$.